# Session Time Out with Laravel

Tags: laravel

Will the default login of Laravel will automatically logged out the Laravel application if the `Session` is timed out?

Comment: Yes, if your session expires, you get logged out. If you like, you can set `config/session.php`'s `lifetime` value to one minute and see.

Comment: I tested it. I idle for a minute but still not redirecting to the login page. Only when I refresh the page that I got redirected to the login page. Is this how it works? Refreshing the page?

Comment: it doesn't redirect automatically when session expired, you have to check with javascript (using ajax) whether session is expire or not. you can use something like `setTimeout`

Comment: if the session expires then the user is logged out, however if there's a remember token set (with checking "remember me") then the user will be logged in again on the next request.

Comment: Hey guys, after the `session` redirects me to login page since it is expired/timed out, then I login, i sometimes get TokenMismatchException

Comment: @MiniDr That happens if you make a `POST` request with the old CSRF token. Make sure you're updating the user's CSRF token if they refresh or get redirected to the login.

Comment: Where to find this method where it redirects to login? so that I can refresh/update it there? @ceejayoz

Comment: @MiniDr Depends on your code. If you're using the `auth` middleware, check `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be logout when the time is over. you can change the session expire time in session.php which is located in config directory.
just change the value of 'lifetime' variable.

```
'lifetime' => 120,
```

you can check [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/session.php)